# Connect my docker to external docker

Tags: python, docker, redis, docker-compose, docker-container

I have a Redis container as a stand alone now I want to connect to this inside my container (another docker container). But I can't seem to successfully connect. Below is the list of docker

[image]

As you can see my container `flexapi_api_1` will try to connect to `localredis` but I always get a connection timeout. When trying to do `docker inspect localredis` I get the result as shown below

[image]

I'm not sure if I need to use the ip `172.17.0.2` as the host ip or I'll use the 0.0.0.0 as host ip for the redis. Is there a way to connect my container to another external container?

Comment: check if redis is running in container, if its running then you can use host_ip or 172.17.0.2(redis container_ip)

Comment: Redis is running but on separate container not within the flexapi_api_1 container.

Comment: then try with host_ip:6379 in flexapi to connect to redis

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can connect from one container to another using the container name as long as the containers are connected to the same network.

Create a network and connect the container to it:

```
docker network create mynet
docker network connect mynet localredis
docker network connect mynet flexapi_api_1
```

Now `flexapi_api_1` should be able to connect to redis via `localredis`